# Quarkus 1.3 cannot instantiate SAXParserFactory

Tags: java, quarkus

I have a SAX Parser Problem when upgrading from Quarkus 1.2.x to 1.3.x.

2 use cases which fail in Quarkus 1.3.x: saxon-HE 10.0 to transform XML via XSLT and docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl 8.1.6 to create OPC packages.
Both fail in javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance() with the message `"javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found"`

Using Quarkus 1.2.x SAXParserFactory successfully creates com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.

When I try to start Quarkus 1.3.x with a system property `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl`

I receive

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory 
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl is in module java.xml of loader 'bootstrap'; 
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader
```

From the release notes at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/releases/tag/1.3.0.Final I could not grab a hint what could have changed this behaviour, so I would be glad for an advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop has the transitive dependency xml-apis:xml-apis.

This has to be excluded, then the XSLT transformation with Saxon also works with Quarkus 1.3.

But why it does not work without exclusion in Quarkus 1.3, but does in Quarkus 1.2, I have no idea. Maybe someone of the quarkus team could shed some light on this.